# Reorganize displays for lockscreen

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, lock-screen

[Ubuntu 20.04]
I have 3 monitors, Each side by side.

The issue is, during normal (while logged in) my main monitor, is of course the one in the middle.
But at the lock screen, the displays are disorganized, the right being the middle(v), the middle being the right(v), and the left being the right(v).

How can I fix this?

*(V) as in how the computer is rendering it

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Solution, Use Ubuntu on wayland to modify the screen order